# Why the installation package of LLVM for Windows does not contain many other LLVM tools?

Tags: windows, llvm

I downloaded the llvm installation package from llvm.org for Windows. However, the tools like llvm-config, llvm-as, llvm-dis are missing and I have to build them on my own. May I know why they are not in the `LLVM-xx.x.x-win64.exe` installation package.